# Xampp сервер видимый на других локальных компьютерах

Tags: xampp

Подскажите что и в каком конфиге нужно поменять в xampp чтобы можно было подключатся к серваку с других компом в локальной сети? В гугле уже искал, VirtualHost создал, в файлах hosts все что нужно прописал, тег LocationMatch в файле httpd-xampp.conf отсутствует

Comment: По умолчанию XAMPP для Windows сконфигурирован для получения доступа к Apache с любых IP-адресов, т.е. с любых компьютеров. Отключите все файрволлы, в т.ч. встроенные в антивирусы и проверьте, осталась ли проблема.

Comment: @kff спасибо, действительно проблема была в файрволле